# Spring mvc HTTP Status 404 - No mapping for GET /spring-mvc/login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-framework-beans

I am running my first spring mvc app but I keep getting file not found exception. I have applied all the things I can find on the internet but none has solved my issue.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring-mvc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

todo-servlet.xml

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.in28minutes" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

LoginController

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String login() {
    return "login";
  }
}
```

My file structure
[image]

url
localhost:8080/spring-mvc/login

Comment: Seems like request mapping should be "/spring-mvc/login" instead of just "/login".

Comment: @lainatnavi I have done that it did not work. Since base url is configured on dispatcher I should not add it again on the mapping.